# Split polyline to equal parts using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

How can a polyline be split to a number of equally long parts using QGIS?

Answer (score 6):

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Split lines by maximum length`.

*Red dots are start-points of the line segments after applying the tool:*

[image]